# Given parallel chords $AB$ and $CD$ on a circle. Prove that the arc length between $A$ and $D$ is equal to the arc length between $B$ and $C$.

Tags: geometry

Given parallel chords $AB$ and $CD$ on a circle. Prove that the arc length between $A$ and $D$ is equal to the arc length between $B$ and $C$.

This is a homework problem just after a section on parallel lines and transversals. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect $A$ to $D$, then angles $\angle BAD \cong \angle CDA$, thus the arc $AC$ equals to arc $BD$, and add arc $CD$ to both to get the desire result.

Comment: How do you show the congruence of the angles?

Comment: Nvm, figured it out. You use the fact that $AD$ is a transversal.

Comment: Because $AB$ and $CD$ are parallel, we may consider the transversal through $AD$. Then $\angle BAD \equiv \angle CDA$ since they form alternate interior angles.